# Product probability

Tags: probability, distributions, random-variable

I have a random variable $Z = XY$, where $Y$ is a random variable of unknown distribution and $X$ is noise induced by a sampling process, which is uniformly distributed in $U(0,1)$. $X$ and $Y$ are independent. $Y$ is from a parametric family and non-negative.

The p.d.f. of $Z$ is given [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_distribution#Derivation):

$$
f_Z(z) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty f_X(x)  f_Y \left (\frac{z}{x} \right )  \frac{1}{|x|} dx,
$$

which simplifies to

$$
f_Z(z) = \int_{0}^1 f_Y \left (\frac{z}{x} \right )  \frac{1}{|x|} dx,
$$

given $X$ is $U(0, 1)$.

First question: is the above correct and useful?

Second question: assuming I have observations for $Z$, how do I apply the formulae above to get the distribution and parameters of $Y$? In the end, I want to be able to sample from $Y$.

Comment: It all depends on what you are willing to assume about the distribution of $Y$.  Two characteristics are particularly important:  Is it a member of a parametric family or not?  Are its values certain to be non-negative or not?

Comment: Yes, $Y$ should be parametric and non-negative. I think that $Y$ is chi square, but I am not sure. I edited my question to reflect your comment.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>If you observe $Z$ and assume $X$ and $Y$ are independent, then, if all you want to do is sample from $Y$, you do not even need to know the pdf of $Z$ or $Y$.</strike>

Say you observe $Z_1,...,Z_n$. Then just draw $X_1,...,X_n \sim U(0,1)$ and set $Y_i = Z_i/X_i$ for $i=1,...,n$.

For an arbitrarily sized sample of $Y$ (one greater than $n$) you could randomly sample from $Z_1,...,Z_n$ and repeat the above.

Thanks to @whuber for pointing out that the above is incorrect.  Instead of doing that, I will propose a Method of Moments (MM) technique for the special case that $Y$ is distributed chi-squared, as suggested in the comments of the original post.

Let $Y\sim \chi (k)$ and $X \sim U(0,1)$.  Note that $E[Z]=E[XY]$.  If $cov[X,Y]=0$, which would be true under independence, then $E[XY]=E[X]E[Y]=.5 \times k$. So $2 \times E[Z]=k$ and finally;
$$
\frac{2}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n Z_i \approx k
$$

you could round the above to estimate the chi-squared parameter.  This estimate is consistent, meaning that as $n \rightarrow \infty$ it will converge on $k$.  However, it is not necessarily the most statistically efficient estimator, meaning that estimators with less variance could be proposed.

Comment: This could be a problem if $Y$ is bounded. For example, if $Y$ had an upper limit of 10 and you observe $Z=8$ and generate a uniform variate of 0.5 Then you will generate a $Y$ realization of 16, which is impossible.

Comment: @soakley that would be true, I didn't think about that.  My impression from above though was that the only restriction on $Y$ was that it was non-negative. I don't think that causes any problems here.

Comment: This solution produces a terribly wrong answer because it implicitly assumes you can invert the operation of multiplying two independent random variables.  If you were to try this out a few times, you would rapidly notice you were getting some outlandish values of $Y_i$, as @soakley observes.

Comment: @whuber.  I don't understand how that would be true if the $X$ and $Y$ were independent so I am probably missing something.  I did notice that when simulating you get large values for $Y$ though.

Comment: Consider one possible realization.  Suppose, say, that $Y_i=2$ and $X_i=1/2$, so that $Z_i=1$. You come along and draw a *new* value of $X_i$, as you describe, and it equals $0.1$, say.  Let's call this value $X_i^\prime$. Your "reconstructed" version of $Y_i$ is $1/(0.1)=10$. It has little connection with the original $Y_i$, because it is equal to $Y_i$ multiplied by the random variable $X_i/X_i^\prime$. You are, in effect, asserting that the distribution of $Y_i$ is the same as that of $Y_i$ times $X_i/X_i^\prime$, but the latter is *much* more spread out.

Comment: @whuber  Thank you for pointing that out.  and I assume this applies to the linear argument as well? i.e. if $Z=X+Y$ then you could not simulate $Y_i = Z_i-X_i$?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.  It's even easier to intuit what's going on there.  Consider the case of standard Normal variates.  Then $Z$ has a variance of $2$ and $Z-X^\prime$ would have a variance of $3$, even though $Y$ only has a variance of $1$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36292/discussion-between-zachary-blumenfeld-and-whuber).