# Sampling a Latent Variable with Unspecified Distribution

Tags: distributions, sampling, latent-variable

This question is an extension of [Product probability](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/198726/product-probability/198789#198789) , although I will use a linear function here in hopes it is more tractable.

Suppose you observe a sample of iid random variables $Z_1,...,Z_n$.  Let $X$ and $Y$ be two mutually independent iid latent variables such that;
$$
Z_i = X_i + Y_i
$$

Suppose you know the distribution of $X_i$, $X_i \stackrel{iid}{\sim} f_X(X)$, but the distribution of $Z_i$ and $Y_i$ are not known*.

The goal is to sample from $f_{Y|Z}(Y\mid Z)$ and ultimately from the marginal $f_{Y}(Y)$.  **Is this possible with the given information?  If so what is(are) the technique(s) for doing so?**

My initial idea was to use the equality $Y_i = Z_i - X_i$, which lead to the false logic that by drawing $X_1,...,X_n \sim f_X(X)$ and setting $Y_i = Z_i - X_i$, we would be effectively sampling from $f_y(Y)$. This does not work (as pointed out in the link above) because the linear function of two random variables cannot be inverted in such a fashion (it also disregards the dependency between $Z$ and $X$).

Currently my idea is to draw $X_i$ from the conditional distribution $f(X\mid Z)$ which, given the marginal, $f_X(X)$, and the covariance matrix;
$$
VAR \begin{pmatrix} Z\\ X \end{pmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} \sigma^2_Z & \sigma^2_X \\ \sigma^2_X & \sigma^2_X \end{bmatrix}
$$
seems like it may be possible, but I am not sure.

*You can assume the support for all random variables is the real line, $\mathbb{R}$, or $\mathbb{R}^k$, $k \in \mathbb{N}$, if you would like to generalize to multivariate (in other words there are no bounds on the random variables).  However, if you can arrive at an interesting non-trivial solution by assuming bounds (such as non-negativity), that answer would be greatly appreciated.